# Teradata tdgssconfig.jar and terajdbc4.jar, Transfer failed 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, maven, teradata

Small question regarding Teradata drivers please.

The Teradata drivers are available in Maven, link here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.teradata.jdbc.com.teradata.jdbc/terajdbc4/16.20.00.12

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.teradata.jdbc/tdgssconfig/16.0.0.28

And maven clearly indicate the repository:

`Note: this artifact is located at EBIPublic repository (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/intact/maven/nexus/content/repositories/public/)`

Therefore, in my Maven POM, I am trying this:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teradata.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>tdgssconfig</artifactId>
            <version>16.0.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teradata.jdbc.com.teradata.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>terajdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>16.20.00.12</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>teradata</id>
            <name>teradata Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://www.ebi.ac.uk/intact/maven/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>teradata</id>
            <name>teradata Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://www.ebi.ac.uk/intact/maven/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

However, while downloading the dependencies:

```
Could not transfer artifact com.teradata.jdbc:tdgssconfig:pom:16.0.0.28 from/to teradata (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/intact/maven/nexus/content/repositories/public/): Transfer failed for https://www.ebi.ac.uk/intact/maven/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/teradata/jdbc/tdgssconfig/16.0.0.28/tdgssconfig-16.0.0.28.pom 500 Internal Server Error
```

I am well aware the jars can be downloaded here for instance:
https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver

But I am wondering what is the issue, and what can be a possible workaround to get those jars from Maven please?

Thank you

Comment: Has nothing directly to do with your issue, but note that from 16.20.00.11 you only need terajdbc4.jar - though a "dummy" tdgssconfig.jar file was still provided until 17.00.

Comment: Learned something new, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 500 problem means that usually something is wrong with a website that you are trying to access. If you can't access the https://www.ebi.ac.uk/intact/maven/nexus/content/repositories/public/ from a web browser there is nothing much to do with that repository.

Comment: Officially, Teradata instructs developers to use the downloads.teradata.com site (or support.teradata.com portal for customers) to download the driver and install to a local repository. The licensing agreement does not permit uploading to public repository.